# A is not in your SSH known_hosts file

Tags: ros, machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm getting this error when trying to launch node on different computer.

```
A is not in your SSH known_hosts file
```

The problem is that the A is in SSH known_hosts. When I set ROSLAUNCH_SSH_UNKNOWN=1 everything works, but I do not want to connect to unknown machines.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41446/a-is-not-in-your-ssh-known_hosts-file./) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-08-15

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2012-08-29**:
Same problem here.
"ssh computer" works fine (doesn't need password because authorized dsa key added), so it's present in ~/.ssh/known_hosts (added on first connection)
But when running a launch with defined machines, it doesn't work (says it's not in known_hosts file!).
Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had the same/similar problem and we have finally solved it.

Roslaunch uses paramiko to create ssh connections, and it seems that paramiko still does not support the ecdsa algorithm, used now as default by last ssh, so it can't read from the known_hosts file generated with ecdsa and can't create the remote connections.

To solve it, we have deleted the known_hosts file (or the line in particular) and regenerated it (storing the new host when asked) doing the first ssh connection with the following command:

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms='ssh-rsa' host
```

So now, roslaunch/paramiko-ssh understands the known_hosts file and can connect to the remote machine.

---

Originally posted by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) with karma: 738 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 30

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kai Bublitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1332/kai-bublitz/) on 2012-08-30**:
Thanks for sharing. I had the same problem, too.
Unfortunately this fix breaks gnomes sftp support in the file manager. I can't connect to my robot from file manager anymore, the console tools give me an option to type "yes" to ignore the offending key, file manager just refuses connection.

**Comment by [adadada](https://answers.ros.org/users/32480/adadada/) on 2017-11-03**:
When I use the command line
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms='ssh-rsa' host
There is an error:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname host: No address associated with hostname
Do you have an ideas about it ? Thank you.

**Comment by [fherrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/2398/fherrero/) on 2017-11-06**:
You need to replace *host* with the correct IPaddress or name (name associated to an IPaddress in your /etc/hosts file) of the computer you are connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that A is in your known_hosts file with the correct key? Try removing it from there and ssh into A manually and store the key. Then try the roslaunch again.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-08-15**:
make sure to use exactly the same hostname when connecting as in the machine tag

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-08-16**:
I have done that, removed the key and log in manually (using command from the error message), added the key, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answers from @fherrero and @osencan can help to work around this issue. However, another option is upgrading `paramiko` to a version `>=2.1.3`. A [PR was merged in February 2017](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/910) that fixes this issue. Ubuntu versions 19.10 and newer ship with versions meeting this criteria. If on 18.04 or older, the upgrade can be accomplished fairly easily with `pip`.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-05-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samarth.robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39083/samarth.robo/) on 2020-10-15**:
Thank you! logged in just to upvote. I think this should be the accepted answer in 2020.